# Is it possible to define a function as an argument of another function in R?

Tags: r, statistics

for example:

```
method1 <- function(alpha,beta,ff)
```

Does R allow this ???

What I am try to achieve is that: I have a general method, `method1`. And I have other methods: `f2,f3,f4`. I want it to be like `method1 <- function(a,b, ff)`, where `a` & `b` are constants and most importantly, `ff` can be either `f2` or `f3` or `f4`, depending on how i call the function on the console. Ideally `f2, f3, f4` computes a matrix.

Using the example in your answer below, I was wondering why cant I have this instead??

```
f1 <- function(a,b,ff(a,b))
{
    solve(ff(a,b))
}
f2 <- function (x,y){
    Diag(x*y)
}
```

This is a really bad example. But I would like to know why cant I include the ff(a,b) in the argument ??? What is the logic of writing ?

f1 <- function(a,b,ff){
ff(a,b)
}

Comment: the logic is that `ff` is the **name** of an argument of the function, and `ff(a,b)` is not a legal name. `ff` is the name of the function; `ff(a,b)` is a call to that function.  The logic of `f1 <- function(a,b,ff) { solve(ff(a,b)) }` is that we pass a function to `f1`, putting it in a slot called `ff`; we then call that function inside the body of `f1` via `ff(a,b)` ... (your example should work fine, and I think do what you want, if you define `f1` as I have done here, rather than as you do in your code block above ...)

Comment: PS if/when a posted answer satisfactorily resolves your question, you can click on the check mark to accept it (you should go back and do that with answers to your other questions if there are good answers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends what you mean.  You can pass a function as an argument to another function, and you can make the default argument a function:

```
f <- function(a,b,f2=function(x,y) { x+y}) {
   f2(a,b)
}
f(1,2) ## 3
```

You can pass the results of a function call:

```
f <- function(a,b,c) { a + b + c }
f3 <- function(x,y) { x*y }
f(1,2,f3(3,4))
```

But you can't do *exactly* what you specified: arguments must be named according to the standard variable-naming conventions (see `?make.names`).

```
f <- function(a,b,f2(1,3)) { ... ## error
```

You can do it by using backticks, or by assigning `names(formals(f))[3] <- "f2(1,3)"`, but that's dangerous and probably not what you wanted.

```
function(a,b,`f2(1,3)`) { }
```

If you explain a little more of the context of what you're trying to do you might get a more meaningful answer ...

**edit**: taking a guess based on your description, you want the first thing I described above.

```
f1 <- function(a,b,ff) {
   ff(a,b) 
}
f2 <- function(x,y) diag(x)*y
f3 <- function(x,y) matrix(runif(x*y),nrow=x,ncol=y)
f4 <- function(x,y) outer(seq(x),seq(y))
f1(2,2,f2)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    0
## [2,]    0    2
f1(2,2,f3)
##             [,1]       [,2]
## [1,] 0.773723089 0.09640121
## [2,] 0.006206349 0.84351541
f1(2,2,f4)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    2
## [2,]    2    4
```

Comment: What I am try to achieve is that: I have a general method, Method1. And I have other methods: f2,f3,f4. I want it to be like Method1 <- function(a,b, ff), where a & b are constants and most importantly, ff can be either f2 or f3 or f4, depending on how i call the function on the console.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot! HOWEVER, may I ask why cant you put f1 <- function(a,b,ff(a,b)){
    ff[1] + 10000
}
f2 <- function(x,y){
diag(3)
}
Why this wouldnt work ??? What is the logic (from what you have written above) of calling ff(a,b) within f1 ??? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean ... can you show an example of input and the desired output, with a bit of the logic connecting the input and output?  It's best to do this as edits to your question, the formatting is nicer and it's easier to read.  In your example here, I don't know (1) where `ff` is defined or what it's supposed to be (it looks like a function in the argument list and a vector in the body of the function) (2) why the body of `f2` ignores its arguments (unless this is just a silly example) ...